# temporary table vs arrays

Tags: php, mysql

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["table"])){
$_SESSION["table"] = uniqid();
$table = $_SESSION["table"];

$query = "
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `" . $table...
```

So each user creates his own temporary table. Clicking on a button, the table is very often updated using jquery ajax.

Technically it seems everything works and I found this as an easier way to handle data, compared with php arrays.

But still I have some dilemmas:

1. Where is the temporary table stored? It doesn't exists in phpMyAdmin?
2. Can be (appache or sql) server too busy updating the tables on each click from many users at the same time ?
3. Is there an easy way to convert this temp. tables to a permanent one ?

Comment: looks like you are vunerable to sql injection with this

Comment: @JohnRuddell, please explain. Where do you see the issue? I didn't submit the entire code because it's not linked to the questions, but all my procedures, including creating the tables are pdo based.

Comment: you didn't specify that originally... from what I can see it looks like you are taking user input and putting it in the query directly - which is why i posted my comment.

Comment: @JohnRuddell, user input ! Where do you see any user input in the submitted code?

Comment: So why are you wanting to do this?  This seems like you will get no net benefit from this, and in fact probably increase your consumption of total system resources (between web server and DB server combined) and increase your overall script execution time.

Comment: @MikeBrant, maybe there is no increased consumption of system resources, especially between web and db server, because it seems the temp. tables are not stored on db server at all. Maybe, they're stored on some kind of php cache, or somewhere. In case they're stored on db server they must be visible in phpMyAdmin, i suppose.

Comment: @bonaca If the are temp tables they are, at a minimum, consuming memory resources on the MySQL server. not too mention connection overhead, CPU cycles, etc.  And it's not like you are shedding memory usage on your app server either, because you will eventually need to get that data into memory in the application to work with it. They would not be visible in PHPMyAdmin because it would use a different connection which does not have access to those temp tables.

Comment: @MikeBrant, I see your point. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. They are only in the scope of a session

According to the docs [**temporary tables are only within the scope of the session you have**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html).

> A TEMPORARY table is visible only to the current session, and is
> dropped automatically when the session is closed. This means that two
> different sessions can use the same temporary table name without
> conflicting with each other or with an existing non-TEMPORARY table of
> the same name.

#### 2. Yes

it would be very taxing to execute multiple statements at the same time... I would recommend you look into putting the queries into an executable function that executes each in order..

#### 3. It is possible

you can store data in a temp table and then you could select it out
see [**Docs**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table-select.html)

To be honest If you want to convert a temporary table into a table in your database I don't know why you wouldn't just create the table and skip the temporary table process altogether... it will make your entire process a lot faster. and you can also look into locking tables for updates after its created incase there are a bunch of updates at the same time.

Comment: John, the reason I want to convert a temp. table to a permanent one is a final user's click at the end of a page. Before that click there is no reason for me to save, but just processing his data. I suppose the processing is faster using temp. table compared to a permanent one.

Comment: @bonaca I am a little baffled why you want to make all of these requests to the sever for a users session... arrays should be much faster... each request is a bunch of wasted time.

Comment: @bonaca sure thing :) you should try using the array and see if its faster I would be surprised if its not :) +1 reciprocated